# Using \citet in IEEETran

Tags: bibliographies, citing, ieeetran

Is there any way to use [`\citet`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/More_Bibliographies#.5Ccitet_and_.5Ccitet.2A) in IEEETran? It's a handy command that IEEETran doesn't support.

Comment: Have you tried loading the `natbib` package? The `\citet` command is provided by the `natbib` package.

Comment: It's not supported because IEEE style doesn't allow you to put in `Author (Year)` citations.

Comment: @percuße -- isn't that a separate (though obviously also very important!) question? I'm pretty sure that the `natbib` package (esp. if loaded with the option `numbers`) is smart enough to make `\citet` behave like `\cite` in such cases.

Comment: @Mico It is indeed but then you can directly use `cite` package as the housestyle recommends in the manual. For `ieeetran` class, there is no difference between `\citet` and `\citep`

Comment: @Mico IEEETran doesn't allow loading `natbib`, with such error: Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.

Comment: @percuße My desired style is like the `\citet` in `classicthesis`: `Author [number]`. Is there any way to define that in a document using IEEETran class?

Comment: That's not allowed *by design* so there is significant effort to prevent that because `ieeetran` is specifically tailored for the journals of IEEE and they don't use author number style. Some authors do that occasionally in their articles manually but usually it's considered to be bad style in an IEEE journal. It's mostly due to saving space as there are hard limits unlike the APA or `natbib` using journals.

Comment: Thanks @percuße. I just noticed that `[number]` is allowed to be used as a noun in IEEE, then I will just use `\cite`

Comment: Ah, yes now I see your motivation. Would you like to answer your own question or do you ming if we close this for housekeeping purposes?

Comment: How if we want a mix style such as in table? We want to mention the researcher, the year it is researched, and then followed by the number stye. Froe example: `Author et al., 2002 [1]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `[number]` is allowed to be used as a noun in IEEE, `\citet` is not necessary. However, I still define a new command `\citet`, but simply make it the same as `\cite`. By doing this, I can reuse the Tex source in different places without needing to change `\citet` to `\cite` when the former is not supported.

Comment: Maybe it can be used, but some people might prefer to also list the author's name to make it more clear.

Answer (score 5):

You can use citet combined with numbers citations by loading:

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}
```

Comment: This did not work for me. Is there anything missing from this snippet to make it work?

Comment: Do you have the IEEE style files? http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtranN.bst