# Get author name and year without registering to reference in IEEETran environment

Tags: bibtex, natbib, ieeetran

I use IEEETran format, and it did not allow natbib as mention in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97794/using-citet-in-ieeetran). I use IEEETran `\cite{}`, but also want to pseudocite `author, year` in table of related works.

The end results will be something like this: `Author et al., 2002 [1]`, that should be easily accomplished if only LaTeX support dual reference style and IEEETran allow default natbib. I would expect something like: `\citep{author:2000} \cite{author:2000}`. Sadly, it said that LaTeX did not support it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/602977/biblatex-multiple-citation-styles-in-the-same-document)?

Note:

1. Don't modify the behavior of `\cite{}` as it is used thorough the document.
2. I use `.tex` file
3. I use `.bib` file

Comment: `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}` is not fully `natbib`-compatible. It can be used with the `numbers` option, but does not provide author-year data. You can try to use `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}`, which should work with `natbib`. (Then `\citeauthor` and `\citeyear` should be available.)

Comment: @moewe Thank you for the information. Sadly, I'm afraid that `IEEEtranN` is not allowed to be used. I don't need to register the bibliography anyway because as I said, the `\cite{}` is still used as the main reference.